# Script Sharp 0.5.5.0 installed for VS2010 and S2008 on the same machine

Tags: .net, visual-studio, script#

I have VS2010 and VS2008 on my laptop and I would like to install Script# in both. However if I install in one of them (2010) when I try to install it on 2008 with the other installer it fails and tell me to uninstall the "old" one first. 
Did someone manage to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, they're not side-by-side. How critical is this scenario?

Comment: Not so critical. so long they are the same version... all I'm missing are the project templates aren't I?

Comment: Yes, thats the only change. I will look at installing for both IDEs with a single setup (probably not next release, but the one after that) ... need more WiX sophistication! :-)